# Run Jira in docker with initial setup snapshot

Tags: docker, jira

In my company, we're using a Jira for issue tracking. I need to write an application, that integrates with it and synchronizes some data with other services. For testing, I want to have a docker image of the Jira with some initial data.

I'm using the official `atlassian/jira-core` image. After the initial setup, I saved a state by running `docker commit`, but unfortunately the new image seems to be empty, and I need to set it up again from scratch.

What should I do to save the initial setup? I want to run tests that will change something within Jira, so reverting it back will be necessary to have reliable test suite. After I spin a new container it should have created a few users, and project with some issues. I don't want to create it manually for each new instance. Also, the setup takes a lot of time which is not acceptable for testing.

Comment: Is working with bind mounts or volumes (https://docs.docker.com/storage) an option for you? Or do you have to setup the instance each time s.t. your Integration tests?

Comment: I don't want to preserve any data after the container is created. So the container should have some initial data, but after container will be gone, the data will be gone with it. Each time I create a new container, it will have the same deterministic set of data. Volumes would be useful if I would want to preserve changes, but it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

To get persistent storage you need to mount `/var/atlassian/jira` in your host system. `/var/atlassian/jira` this can be used for storing your configuration etc. so you do not need to commit, whenever you spin up a new container with `/var/atlassian/jira` mount path will have all the configuration that you set previously.

```
docker run --detach -v /you_host_path/jira:/var/atlassian/jira --publish 8080:8080 cptactionhank/atlassian-jira:latest
```

For logs you can mount

```
/opt/atlassian/jira/logs
```

The above is valid if you are running with the latest tag or  you can explore relevant [dockerfile](https://github.com/cptactionhank/docker-atlassian-jira).

> Set volume mount points for installation and home directory. Changes to the
>   home directory needs to be persisted as well as parts of the installation
>   directory due to eg. logs. `VOLUME ["/var/atlassian/jira", "/opt/atlassian/jira/logs"]`

[atlassian-jira-dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/cptactionhank/atlassian-jira/dockerfile)

Comment: But I don't want the data to be persistent between containers. I just want a container to have initial data. All changes should be gone with the container, so the new container will have the same data.

Comment: initialize you container once with persistent storage, do you configuration with that container. now you have everything under `home_path/jira`.  consider this `initial data`. Now rebuild your image with `copy home_path/jira /var/atlassian/jira` and run the container so you will not need to mount in the new container will have every thing that you iniated previously

Comment: Well - using volume, in this case, is not different from the docker commit. Anyway, Jira seems to ignore the filesystem changes (note that I use the official `atlassian/jira-core` image).

Answer (score 0):

look at the [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/cptactionhank/docker-atlassian-jira/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) , the comments from there are:

> check if the `server.xml` file has been changed since the creation of
>   this Docker image. If the file has been changed the entrypoint script
>   will not perform modifications to the configuration file.

so I think you need to provide your `server.xml` to stop the init process...

Comment: It isn't the official `atlassian/jira-core` image, right? I cannot find such file in the official image.

Comment: it is the same concept , jut provide the xml files and the init process will not start and you have the required data

Comment: Any clue what the `server.xml` should look like to stop the process? I'm looking at the file within the image and I see no option for that.

Comment: just create the container with your configs and then take that file out from the container and copy to others to start new containers with the modified file...

Comment: If I understand correctly, `docker commit` + modifying the file after the new container has been created should do the trick in this case (after container will be restarted). However, it seems like it doesn't help. Did I misunderstand something?